# Show External Component On Checkbox Click Between Two Stateless Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Am a bit new to react and redux. I am trying to call/show another stateless component's div from parent component. For example, if I have the below code

```
const funcA = ({key}) = > {
  return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
  );
};
export default funcA


const funcB = ({key}) = > {
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
         <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="age" />
         </div>
         <div id="showThisDiv">
            <input type="text" placeholder="age" />
         </div>
      </React.Fragment>

  );
};
export default funcB
```

I am not trying go with classes. In Stateless components I know how to show/hide a section by using the useState, but I can only do this while in the same component. The issue or rather the challenge, is when I try to show/hide a section from another component. How would I show/hide the div with id showThisDiv in funcB when the checkbox is toggled in funcA?

Comment: Wrap them in a common parent component, send data from the child via a function prop that update some kind of state on the parent that then gets passed to the other child to show/hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, is something like this:

EDIT:

```
// ComponentA.js
const ComponentA = props => <input type="checkbox" onChange={props.onChange} />

// ComponentB.js
const ComponentB = props => (
  <>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="age" />
    </div>
    {props.visible && (
      <div id="showThisDiv">
        <input type="text" placeholder="age" />
      </div>
    )}
  </>
)

// App.js
const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentA onChange={() => setVisible(!visible)} />
      <ComponentB visible={visible} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Now as you want..

Comment: @Diego Lessa Am trying to use stateless components.

Comment: Hi... made a tweak for you

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using redux, but you also can do it using state and react hooks:

check out this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-driscoll-odqmo

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import FuncA from "./FuncA";
import FuncB from "./FuncB";

export default function App() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0);
   handleInput = (event) => {
     console.log(event.target.value);
     setAge(age === 0 ? 1 : 0);
   }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <FuncA age={age}  onChange={handleInput} />
      <FuncB age={age} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

FuncA.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function FuncA(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="age" onChange={props.onChange} value={props.age} />
      </label>
    </>
  );
}
```

FuncB.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function FuncB(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.age === 0 && <div className="divA">show div a</div>}
      {props.age === 1 && <div className="divB">show div b</div>}
    </>
  );
}
```